# Duplicate entry error for primary key which is autoincrement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting duplicate entry error for primary key which is autoincrement field defined in table.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 1' in
```

I am trying to add an entry to the table at the almost same time. That could be the possible reason but i am not sure.

Actually multiple ajax call running behind the scene and they are sometime trying to add entry in table with same primary key at the same time.

I guess this is the issue of autogeneration of same primary key by sql engine.

Mysql table type:MyISAM.

What can be done to fix this?

Table definitions: result_id is a primary key field

[image: Table defintion]

I have writren PDO wrapper for database entry, although i am using this databound object from last year and no issues found. Attaching some portion as requested in comment.

Note: ID(primary key) is not a part of INSERT statement.

```
$valueList = "";
$query     = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->tableName . ' (';


foreach ($this->relationMap as $key => $value) {
    eval('$actualVal = &$this->' . $value . ';');

    if (isset($actualVal)) {
        if (array_key_exists($value, $this->modifiedRelations)) {
            $query .= $key . ', ';
            $valueList .= ":$value, ";
        }
    }
}


$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 2);

$valueList = substr($valueList, 0, strlen($valueList) - 2);
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= $valueList;
$query .= ")";
//prepare and execute codes - here
$this->ID = $this->objPDO->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Show us the SQL query you're executing, and the table definition

Comment: Show us `$this->relationmap' as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read this](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-o-1844.html)

Or

You have set result_id already in primary key according to your sanpshot

but i think you have not set is auto_increment

Please set primary key with auto_increment

Comment: i saw this article before posting this question. His solution is to drop database and recreate the DB, that's not a solution, i will encounter this issue frequently due to same time entries in tables

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Link only answers are discouraged!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) Please write a full answer, instead of just providing a link.

Answer (score 0):

First delete the row with id = 1  (the first record), then edit the table structure by setting the Auto_Increment attribute of the id field to 'True'(by clicking the Auto_Increment checkbox and save.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is (( AUTO_INCREMENT ))